# Windows 7 VM constantly suspends

Tags: windows, virtualization

I have a Windows 7 Virtual PC that hosts a Windows 7 guest operating system.

When I start the VM and log into the Windows 7 guest OS it will suspend every 2-5 seconds.  I have to then choose Action->Wake up from the VM's menu.

When I go into power management to turn off Sleep there is no selection for it!  Normally I can set it to never.

This is driving me crazy.  Does anyone have any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

Really weird.

Seems like somehow the hardware detect by W7 in the guest got screwed. No idea how or why this happens but I may have a workaround for you:

Why don't you try to change the motherboard chipset driver in the VM definition ?
That should force a complete hardware re-detect by the guest OS.
Let it boot. And reboot a couple of times to re-detect hardware/install all drivers.

Then switch back to the original definition and reboot a couple of more times.

Hopefully that will fix it.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.  Would I do that in the VM bios?

Comment: I actually overlooked that in your question. I was thinking VirtualBox. To be honest I don't know if you can change this in VirtualPC. I have never used it.

Comment: Ok.  I am re-installing from scratch now.  Hopefully it will go better the second time around.